# How to use $asyncValidators with angularjs and set a warning message in the HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

This is my first bigger form with validations and etc.
I've created a Registration form and I'm using ng-messages for validation. The problem is that I need to validate the **username**, does it already exist in the JSON server that we are using or it's available. Of course, if it's taken the warning pops out in the HTML where the username input is, if it's available the submit button is no more disabled (because the form will be $valid) and the user can register. I want to use **angular-sanitize** because I found this (I don't know if they are related):

```
    ngModel.$asyncValidators.uniqueUsername = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
      var value = modelValue || viewValue;

      // Lookup user by username
      return $http.get('/api/users/' + value).
         then(function resolved() {
           //username exists, this means validation fails
           return $q.reject('exists');
         }, function rejected() {
           //username does not exist, therefore this validation passes
           return true;
         });
    };
```

Here is the code I use now (reg form, controller and service):

```js
// Controller:
export default class registerPageController {
  constructor(userService, authenticationService, $location) {
    this.register = "Register";
    this.userService = userService;
    this.$location = $location;
    this.authenticationService = authenticationService;
    this.hasLoggedIn = false;
  }

  onSubmit(user) {
    let self = this;
    let {
      name,
      age,
      email,
      username,
      password
    } = user;
    self.userService.register(name, age, email, username, password).then((res) => {
        self.userService.login(username, password).then(function (response) {
          let data = response.data;

          if (data.length) {
            let user = data[0];
            self.hasLoggedIn = true;
            self.authenticationService.setCredentials(username, password);
            self.$location.path('/');
          }
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        // WHAT TO PUT HERE AFTER THE USERNAME EXIST VALIDATION ?
      })
  }
}

// Service:

export class UserService {
  constructor($http) {
    this.$http = $http;
  }

  login(username, password) {
    return this.$http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/users',
      params: {
        username: username,
        password: password
      }
    });
  }

  register(name, age, email, username, password) {
    return this.$http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/users',
      data: {
        name: name,
        age: age,
        email: email,
        username: username,
        password: password
      }
    });
  }

// SHOULD I PUT HERE THE USERNAME EXIST VALIDATION LOGIC ?

}
```

```html
<div class="container main-content">
  <form class="registrationForm" name="registerForm" ng-submit="register.onSubmit(register.user)" novalidate="novalidate">

    <!-- Enter Name -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name" class="control-label"><span id="reqInfo">*</span> Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="register.user.name" ng-pattern="/[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]+/" id="name"
        required="" placeholder="Example: Petar Petrov">
      <div ng-messages="registerForm.name.$error" ng-show="registerForm.name.$touched" style="color:maroon" role="alert">
        <div ng-message="required">Your name is required</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- User Age-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="age" class="control-label"><span id="reqInfo">*</span> Age</label>
      <input type="number" name="age" class="form-control" ng-model="register.user.age" ng-min="18" min="18" id="age" required=""
        placeholder="Enter your age">
      <div ng-messages="registerForm.age.$error" ng-show="registerForm.age.$touched" style="color:maroon" role="alert">
        <div ng-message="min">You must be at leats 18 years old</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Enter E-mail -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email" class="control-label"><span id="reqInfo">*</span> E-mail</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" ng-model="register.user.email" ng-pattern="/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+|(?:www\.|[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/\.\w\-_]*)?\??(?:[\-\+=&;%@\.\w_]*)#?(?:[\.\!\/\\\w]*))?)/"
        id="email" required="" placeholder="Example: mail@mail.net">
      <div ng-messages="registerForm.email.$error" ng-show="registerForm.email.$touched" style="color:maroon" role="alert">
        <div ng-message="required">Your valid e-mail is required</div>
      </div>
      <br>

      <!-- Enter Username -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username" class="control-label"><span id="reqInfo">*</span> Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="20" class="form-control" ng-model="register.user.username"
          ng-pattern="/^[A-Za-z0-9_]{1,32}$/" ng-minlength="7" id="username" required="" placeholder="Enter your username">     
        <div ng-messages="registerForm.username.$error" style="color:maroon" role="alert">
          <div ng-message="minlength">Your Username must be between 7 and 20 characters long</div>
        </div>
        <br>

        <!-- Enter Password -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="password" class="control-label"><span id="reqInfo">*</span> Password</label>
          <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" ng-model="register.user.password" ng-minlength="7" id="password"
            required="" placeholder="Enter your password">
          <div ng-messages="registerForm.password.$error" style="color:maroon" role="alert">
            <div ng-message="minlength">You Password must be at least 7 symbols long</div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Register button -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ng-disabled="!registerForm.name.$valid || !registerForm.age.$valid || !registerForm.email.$valid || !registerForm.username.$valid || !registerForm.password.$valid">Register</button>
        </div>
        <p>Fields with <span id="reqInfo">*</span> must be filled.</p>
  </form>
  </div>
```

Important is to know that I have being told explicitly to write it in ES6.
I have problem with the logic so look at my code and please fill it for me so I can use it and most important - learn it :S 
Thank you so so much in advance!

Comment: When asking homework questions, ask about specific problems with your existing implementation. See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a directive for different kind of validations (sync Async), and it supports warning as well.
You may check it from

```
`https://plnkr.co/2WQHOo`
```

If this is what you needed and need more information, let me know I will try my best to answer.